# Is a native android login for website in webview in android even possible?

Tags: php, android, mysql, webview

I have a webservice where users can login and I want to build an android app for it. Basically, for now I want to use a webview to display the mobile website.

Is it possible to build a native login for this though? So a users logs in with the native login and then the webview is displayed where a session or cookie is set.

How would you build this globally?

Comment: No, I need webview for the part after the native login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be two ways to achieve this

1. Use any of the hybrid app tools like [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/), [Xamrin](http://xamarin.com/), [Qt](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Qt_hybrid_applications), and you will have to do minimal coding for giving a native look for your app. [**advantage** : you could make app for all the platforms directly using this code]
2. Write a basic Android app with dialog on the first screen with login

And provide API within you web service for this login functionality and store cookie and other data in the webview.